# Tax deduction for donating to international charity

Tags: tax-deduction, australia, charity, charitable-contributions

If one sponsors a child from an impoverished country through a charity like Save the Children international, can this contribution still be considered tax deductible in Australia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically to know if a charity is tax deductible in Australia you should do a search on 'ABN Lookup'.

In 'ABN Lookup' if you type "Save the children" in the search box it will come up with a few different ABNs. The head office for Save The Children Australia is in Victoria, so you could select the ABN that corresponds to Save the Children Australia located in Victoria.

Down the bottom under: **Deductible gift recipient status** it reads:

> SAVE THE CHILDREN AUSTRALIA is endorsed as a Deductible Gift Recipient (DGR) from 17 May 2017. It is covered by Item 1 of the table in section 30-15 of the Income Tax Assessment Act 1997 .
>
> SAVE THE CHILDREN AUSTRALIA operates the following funds, authorities
>   or institutions. Gifts to these funds, authorities or institutions may
>   be deductible.
>
> Fund, authority or institution name: SCF OVERSEAS RELIEF FUND

If you have already made a donation and you know the name of the fund or the actual ABN, then you can look up these details to see the **Deductible gift recipient status** for your donation.